# Start time once game is complete

Tags: jquery, html

JSFiddle: [**JS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bbGV7/)

The HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <input type=button value="Start Game" id=sGame class=sGame />
    Timer: <input type=text class=timer id=timer value="" READONLY />

    <br><br>
    <div id="cardPile"> </div>
    <div id="cardSlots"> </div>
    <div id="successMessage">
        <h2>You did it in <span class="time"></span> seconds!</h2>
        <button onclick="init()">Play Again</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The issue I am having is once the PLAY AGAIN button is clicked the timer is not restarting from 0. I tried the following code

```
$('#sGame').click();
```

inside the

```
init();
```

function, but the timer starts off even before the Start Game button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**if (timer !== null) clearInterval(timer), value = 0;**

If the timer is NOT null (it's running) -> clear the interval, set the **value** variable to 0, then restart the interval.

```
$('#sGame').click(function () {
    if (timer !== null) clearInterval(timer), value = 0;
    timer = setInterval(function () {
        value = value + 1;
        $("#timer").val(value);
    }, interval);
    $('#cardPile').show('slow');
    $('#cardSlots').show('slow');
});
```

Comment: See edit above. Just resets the timer, you still have to reset the 'game.'

Comment: The game resets itself but the time does not start over again.

Comment: Is that the only line that was added new? Heres the link: http://www.interfaithmedical.com/time.htm and after adding your code, the timer does not restart on the new game.